# Magento2 - How to extend jQuery widget (configurable.js)

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I'm creating an extension that replaces the default configurable options label 'Choose an Option...' with the attribute name, for example 'Choose a Color...'.

How can I extend (not override!) the jQuery widget configurable.js and only modify this line?

I know from the documentation that I can override a jQuery widget, so I did:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'configurable' // usually widget can be found in /lib/web/mage dir
], function($){

    $.widget('silvan.configurable', $.mage.configurable, {

    });

    return $.silvan.configurable;
});
```

How can I initialize this file? Should I load it via requirejs-config? The map function is only for overriding right?

Is it possible to only modify this line? It's called from this function:

```
_fillSelect: function (element) {}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make sure, that your module has `Magento_ConfigurableProduct` in sequence in `module.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Make sure to regenerate the component list in `config.php`, otherwise the sequence will be ignored (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html)

Then add `requirejs-config.js` file in `view/frontend` directory with code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            configurable: 'Vendor_ModuleName/js/configurable'
        }
    }
};
```

Finally add `configurable.js` file in `view/frontend/web/js` directory with:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'priceUtils',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'
], function($, priceUtils){

    $.widget('silvan.configurable', $.mage.configurable, {
        //code you want to override
    });

    return $.silvan.configurable;
});
```

You can't modify a single line, but you can modify a single function inside.

Comment: How does modifying a function work? How to call the parent?

Comment: You can call functions other than one you modify just like it was part of your widget. Your `silvan.configurable` automatically inherits all from parent.

Comment: This works great, thank you @Ideo! Bounty will be given in 7 hours (limit of stackexchange). @Alex you can call the parent by using the this._super(); function. See: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/#using-_super-and-_superapply-to-access-parents

Comment: is there anything else todo ? cause my custom file wont get loaded... did it exact as it is described above :-(

Comment: Is it possible to do the same but only directrly for theme? I use ```configurable: 'js/configurable-custom'``` but it does not work for me. The definition is in the requirejs file but js/configurable-custom.js is still not included

Comment: This works great!
@roman204 I got the same issue: make sure you have the "sequence" node in your module.xml file. Then it's important to reload the module order. The only way to do it at the moment is to disable and re-enable the module where you put the "sequence" in the module.xml file. (More info: view the blue part on this page: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html)

Comment: Hi, I've following this but have no luck, please help, thanks. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262868/how-to-override-magento-configurableproduct-js-configurable-js

Comment: This method may appear to work initially but on further investigation it seems there is a problem. You cannot override a function that makes calls to other functions in configurable.js. Functions in the custom js file can't access the functions in the base configurable.js and that breaks functionality. You have to copy the entire configurable.js from the magento module and then edit it. I think using the mixin strategy is probably better.