# Magento 2: set configurable product option via js

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, javascript

I would like to automatically set a configurable product option.

I tried to do it via javascript:

```
<script>
    require(["jquery", "jquery/ui"], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#attribute93').val(12).change();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The hardcoded id and value are for testing purposes only (both do exist). 
The problem seems to be that the `ready` function is called before the dropdown select is completely rendered and ready for user interaction. `$('#attribute93').val(12).change();` does work when triggered by a user's click.

Is there a way to tell when everything on a page is completely rendered? I found the `afterRender` event but that seems to relate to knockout js only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the perfect solution:

1. Override configurable.js from Magento_Configurable module. Explained here: [Magento2 - How to extend jQuery widget (configurable.js)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131192/magento2-how-to-extend-jquery-widget-configurable-js)
2. override function `_onGalleryLoaded()`

   ```
   define(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'], function($){
   $.widget('om.configurable', $.mage.configurable, {
        _onGalleryLoaded: function (element) {
           var galleryObject = element.data('gallery');
           this.options.mediaGalleryInitial = galleryObject.returnCurrentImages();

           $('#attribute93').val(13).change();
       },
   });

   return $.om.configurable;
   ```

   });

Works like a charm.