# How to override Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.js

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, overrides

I'm following this instruction to override `"Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.js"` but it doesn't work.
I'm following this link:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131852/70258

After i disable module and then enable the module again, then run **setup:upgrade, content:deploy**, then it become this:
[image]

Now i can't see the related product anymore, i guess that `Magento_ConfigurableProduct` javascript is broken.

Here are my files:

> module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Convert_ProductList" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> configurable.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'
], function($){

    $.widget('silvan.configurable', $.mage.configurable, {
        //code you want to override
    });

    return $.silvan.configurable;
});
```

> app\code\Convert\ProductList\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            configurable:'Convert_ProductList/js/configurable'
        }
    }
};
```

Here is my tree code:

[image]

Comment: Try this 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261628/magento-2-how-to-put-custom-text-in-form-validation?noredirect=1#comment369281_261628

Comment: @GPrathap i don't get it, what's the different?

Comment: Where is your requirejs-config.js file is placed?

Comment: You should add full file path.

Comment: I've take a picture of tree code up there. Please check.

Comment: Hi, thanks all for your help, i was put this in default mode (it should be developer mode), that how i can't see any error but it still doesn't work. Also, right now, i'm using "mixin" to make this work. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html